# C: unsigned long int not behaving as expected

Tags: c

This code is not behaving as expected.  It simply tries to set bit 31 in an unsigned long int.

```
int main() {
    printf("sizeof(unsigned long int) is %ld bytes\n", sizeof(unsigned long int));
    unsigned long int v = 1 << 30;
    printf("v is (%lx)\n", v);
    v = 1 << 31;
    printf("v is (%lx)\n", v);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
sizeof(unsigned long int) is 8 bytes
v is (40000000)
v is (ffffffff80000000)
```

Can anyone explain this?  Maybe a problem with the printf formatting?

Comment: in short: `1UL << 30`

Comment: Yep.  That was it.  Thanks.  I never would have figured that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `v = 1 << 31;`, `1` is not an `unsigned long int`. It is an `int`. Shifting it by 31 bits overflows the `int` type (in your C implementation).

To get an `unsigned long int` with a 1 in bit 31, you should shift an `unsigned long int` by 31 bits: `v = (unsigned long int) 1 << 31;` or `v = 1ul << 31`.

Comment: Thanks.  That solves it.